# is there any way of finding mime type of all URLs I go through

Tags: python

for ex- url="https://example.com" and I have a url_1="https://www.example.com/asb.html"
i want to find the mime type of both URL
I used
import mime type module of python
but it is showing mime type only if it ends with .html or .pdf or whatever
but what if I need the mime type of the first URL because obviously it will also have a mime type in it
I need mime type of all the URLs I go through
so if anyone can help me with it in python

Comment: check the magic number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Make a HEAD request to the URL and then get the mime-type/content-type from the headers

```
import requests
response = requests.head('https://example.com')
print(response.headers['content-type'])
```

If HEAD requests are not supported you can use `get()` although this will be slightly less efficient